# Local web application or windows application for my system

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-services

I am going to design system that will keep track of publications due by researchers in my work place

Need for this project :

1- a database housing the information .

2- Automatic reports must be generated .

the users will upload PDF and we have around 25 researchers.
I can’t decide which one is better for my system .

My questions are :

1- Local web application or windows application ?

2- Access or SQL as database ?

3- I have visual studio 2010 for student use, Could I use it or I need to buy one ?

Thanks in advance

Mark

from new zealand

Answer (score 2):

1) Either a web or Windows application can work here, although a web application would work better if they are geographically spaced far apart, or if you had a lot more than 25 researchers. I would recommend that you program on the platform that is most comfortable to you. In either case, you should implement some kind of authentication scheme so that only authorized researchers can upload data.

2) SQL database.

3) I don't know what are the licensing terms for the student editions (read carefully!), but if you're so worried about that, then you can use the [Express Editions of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/). Those in fact [can be used for commercial development.](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx)

Comment: +1, agree with everything except with 3) - check out the exact license of your student software. Use in a University environment is not commercial use per se, but also not purely private either.